# How do I synchronise two servers for changes in files as well as database?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, file-management, database-management

I have a PHP/Mysql Desktop server. I also installed PHP/Mysql to my laptop and one of my friends for developing a project. Is there anyway that we can synchronise all the changes (i.e. to the php files as well as database changes whether structural or data wise) we do on our laptops to desktop PC ?

Comment: use source code management, e.g. cvs/git/hg/whatever..., though that won't help with the DB.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you want to start using Git, possibly with a free private repository on somewhere like www.bitbucket.org.   Within your versioning, you can backup a version of your SQL inside of the phpMySQL admin tool, and clone the entire repository every time you want to move it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few choices
https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd#readme
will sync real time and uses inotify

and if you want to go real nerd
http://www.drbd.org/
High availability clustering

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way (if you just want the files synced as is on each change) would be to use something like **Google Drive** or a similar service. Though if you want revision history and more advanced tools, you'd probably need some sort of **version control repository** (git, svn, etc.).

However, I definitely recommend version control if that works for you.  And if you go with git, I highly recommend [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) as they have free closed source hosting for projects of up to 10 (last time I checked) people.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would to be purchase a VPS from a company like [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for $5.00 a month.  You can then setup a MySQL database that you can both easily connect to.  In addition, you will be able to use it to test and deploy (smaller) projects to the server.

Forgot to address the other part of your question.  You will be able to setup git/SVN/CVS on this server as well.  There are good tutorials online for this.  You can both access and commit your changes to this repository.  You could also use a website like GitHub for this version control.

Answer (score 0):

Along with a version control system (such as [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/), [Git](http://git-scm.com/), or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)) you can't go wrong with using a tool such as [FreeFileSync](http://freefilesync.com/) (free as in freeware) for a quick and easy way to push the changes you make to a project to a centralized location. With your project included in a VCS repository the VCS you choose to use will give you control over how you want your project to be synchronized.

This has helped me a lot over the years and has even made the process faster.